# Linq from CSV source return empty record on VB.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, csv

I have data extract from csv using vb.net as below code

```
    Dim district As New List(Of tbDistrict)

    Dim path As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "tb_district.csv"
    Dim results = (From line In File.ReadAllLines(path)
                   Let value = line.Split(";").
                                    Select(Function(x) x)
                   Select New With {.district_id = value(0),
                                    .district_code = value(1),
                                    .amphur_id = value(2),
                                    .district_name = value(3),
                                    .province_id = value(4)}).ToList()
    'Console.WriteLine(results.Count)
    For Each item In results
        district.Add(New tbDistrict With {
                .district_id = item.district_id,
                .district_code = item.district_code,
                .district_name = item.district_name,
                .amphur_id = item.amphur_id,
                .province_id = item.province_id
             })
    Next
```

I have 2000 records add to list. Then I try to use linq to get some record by using below code

```
    Dim provinceid As String = "1"
    Dim amphurid As String = "1"
    Dim mystring As String = "test"

    Dim searchtabbol As List(Of tbDistrict) = district.Where(Function(x) _
                                                    (x.province_id = provinceid) AndAlso
                                                    (x.amphur_id = amphurid) AndAlso
                                                    (x.district_name.Contains(mystring.Trim()))).ToList()

    Console.WriteLine(searchtabbol.Count)
```

But I get 0 record return although row exist. I'm not sure what's wrong in code?. Appreciated for all advise.

Comment: since we have no idea what's in your data, or what the expected result should be, it's hard to say exactly what kind of mistake you may have made.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data of province_id , amphur_id & district_name in that csv file.